# How do I use the spaceDelimted parser in SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to use the spaceDelimted parser in my SBT plugin.

However, the "spaceDelimited" function cannot be found.. do I have to include it somehow?

```
object MyPlugin extends Plugin {

    lazy val testInput = inputKey[Unit]("A demo input task.")

    lazy val mySettings = Seq(
        testInput := {
            val args: Seq[String] = spaceDelimited("<arg>").parsed
            args foreach println
        }
    )

}
```

The above code cannot compile because "spaceDelimited" is not found...

How do I make it such that the "spaceDelimited" is found-- do I need to include some package?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer, I just needed to add this line

```
import sbt.complete.DefaultParsers._
```

This will import the spaceDelimited parser